# Best practice when dealing with multiple results from a query/multiple queries?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

This is the first time I'll be making a PHP application that will have many users accessing it so where as before I didn't have to worry about loading speeds, I do now.

These are the ways I have thought of doing it but they all seem to be a bit "hack-ish" and I'm sure there is a better way.

For the index page I could have this:

```
<h1><?php $job->getTitle($id); ?></h1>
<p><?php $job->getDescription($id); ?></p>
<p><?php $job->getSomethingElse($id); ?></p>
```

And the class as:

```
function getTitle($id) {
    $query = "SELECT title FROM table WHERE id = $id";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo $row['title'];
}

function getDescription($id) {
    $query = "SELECT description FROM table WHERE id = $id";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo $row['description'];
}
```

etc...

Or I could have one function, call all the results to an array. Store them as a String and explode them as I need them.

My other idea was similar to above, except I do everything in the class and echo the html.

What is the best way in terms of speed to output what I want?

Comment: If it's possible try to get all data from database once!

Comment: That's what I thought, I just wasn't sure of the best approach and wanted to show I'd thought about all my options.

My knowledge of OOP comes from Java and have never used it with database connections. So mixing this with my limited knowledge of procedural PHP.

Could the person who down voted please explain why. I tried to follow the rules in regards to asking a question.

In regards to the answers, they all look like they'll work well for what I want so I'll give them all a try and mark a best answer after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jee, have You ever listened about the MVC (Model-View-Controller) design pattern?

Though I do not want You to rewrite whole Your app, You still can get used to using of Models... By this (in very simple way) way You create a `class Model` that has a `__construct($id)` method that queries the DB to load all the necessary data and store them within a private/publi/protected (whatever makes You feel good) properties.

Then You call these `getXYZ()` methods on that model that only returns it's property values...

Like this:

class Article {
        private $title;
        private $description;
        private $somethingElse;

```
    public function __construct($id) {
        $query = "SELECT title, description, somethingElse FROM table WHERE id = $id";
        $result = $db->query($query);

        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $this->title = $row['title'];
        $this->description = $row['description'];
        $this->somethingElse = $row['somethingElse'];
    }

    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function getSomethingElse() {
        return $this->somethingElse;
    }
```

That's it... Just one query to retrieve all the data...

In a case You want to also edit this model You can create also a `setXYZ($value)` methods that will set `$this->XYZ = $value;` and a `save()` method that will update this very concrete row in the database...

These methods (get and set) are called getters and setters...

Comment: Isn't it bad practice in itself to select all rather than just the columns you need?

Comment: @AlexL Yes, it is, I was just demonstrating the getter methods, not the query itself... But I will change it :-)

Comment: This worked perfect thanks. I would vote up but my question has been voted down. If I gain the reputation I'll come back and vote it up.

Comment: what has Voting up an answer with Voting down your question?

Comment: My rep was below 15 at the time as my question has been voted down. Therefore I didn't have enough rep to upvote. Anyway, since I do now, I've upvoted your answer.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I think its better execute query one time .. So fetch all details what you want and use it whenever you want

```
 function getDetails($id){
     $query = "SELECT title,description FROM table WHERE id = $id";
     $result = $db->query($query);

     return $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

 }
```

And you can use like

```
 <?php  $details = $job->getDetails($id); ?>
 <h1><?php echo $details['title']; ?></h1>
 <p><?php echo $details['description']; ?></p>
```

I don't know more about this....

Answer (score 2):

Make a a getter and setter for each property, run 1 query, set all variables and use the getters to get the actual value.

Something like this should work:

```
    private $name;
    private $street;
    private $number;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setNumber($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;
    }

    public function getNumber()
    {
        return $this->number;
    }

    public function setStreet($street)
    {
        $this->street = $street;
    }

    public function getStreet()
    {
        return $this->street;
    }


    public function getUser()
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE x = y";

        $this->setName($result['name']);
        $this->setStreet($result['street']);
        $this->setName($result['number']);

    }
```

Comment: Doesn't save any typing for me. If you use a decent IDE, it's hardly any work at all. I generate all getters and setters in 10 seconds. Magic getters and setters never give a good representation of the object you're dealing with and prevent you from writing property-specific code.